# Extension Installation Event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there anyway to detect installation of a new extension or whenever an extension is updated in an other extension. e.g.
If I install a "xyz" extension I get an event in "abc" that xyz is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the management APIs:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#event-onInstalled